# Telephone number displays below description in Google

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, local-seo

I've noticed that Google is displaying a phone number immediately below some descriptions in the organic SERPs.  It displays as a line below the description with the telephone icon next to it.

Looking at the websites displaying this, they appear to be using:

```html
<span itemprop="telephone">555-212-1212</span>
```

Is this replacing the `<a href="telephone">555-212-1212</a>` syntax?

Is Google looking for the `itemprop` syntax in order to display the telephone number below the SERP description?

[image: Google Search: search results showing the telephone number below the description]

Comment: Related: https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister, thanks.  That's helpful.  Are we assuming that Google is using the microdata to display the phone number in the SERP?